# JMeter not reading variable from CSV file

Tags: csv, jmeter

I'm new to Jmeter and am trying to use variables from a CSV file in the path of my HTTP GET request.

I've looked through various tutorials and answers to this question, but I still can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. The file just has one header (ID). It works if I enter the ID in the path, but as soon as I try read it from the CSV file, it fails:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's in the jmeter log?

Comment: C:\Automation\Test.csv 
2017/03/01 12:35:26 WARN  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Unable to encode parameter in encoding json, parameter value not included in query string 
2017/03/01 12:35:26 WARN  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Unable to encode parameter in encoding json, parameter value not included in query string

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration looks good, double check *jmeter.log* file for any suspicious entries.

Other recommendations:

- Given you have only a single column it might be easier to use [__StringFromFile() function](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile) directly in the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler body like:

  ```
  /api/Users/${__StringFromFile(c:\Automation\Test.csv,,,)}
  ```
- I believe `Content-Type` and `Authorization` should go in [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager), not in the request parameters

See [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter) article for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't with the reading of the variable. I thought that the first line of the file would be treated as a header, but it reads the first line of the file as a variable, so my file looked like:

ID
001

It read "ID", when I wanted it read "001.

Comment: There's a setting in the CSV Data Set Config called "Ignore first line". This is false by default; you want to set it to true.